# Is there a property I can use to specify the location of my jetty.xml?

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am preparing a distribution of my application and it contains a Jetty. I would like to be able to specify the location of my `jetty.xml` file as a property via my `JSW`-generated scripts. Is there such a property that I can use?

Is there some page that lists the system properties that can be used Jetty?

Comment: Embedded? or Jetty Distribution based?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure. I am getting Jetty via Maven dependencies. I ended up knocking up a class that launches Jetty (as can be seen here: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox-assembly/blob/master/strongbox-jetty-booter/src/main/java/org/carlspring/strongbox/servers/jetty/JettyLauncher.java), but I was initially hoping to be able to do it by re-using Jetty's `Main` class.

Comment: That would be embedded-jetty then, let me correct your tags

Comment: If you are using embedded-jetty, there's no need for `jetty.xml` (that's something that the jetty-distribution and its `start.jar` is responsible for).  The fact that you are using embedded-jetty means you can do everything in standard Java.  Is that more appealing?